# Granular access control with loopback

Tags: javascript, loopbackjs, loopback

I'm using the latest version of loopback and I'd like to work on the acl now. My app has a project model that should be available tontge team members, relative owner and admin. Of course I would like to have multiple projects with members that can be team member in multiple projects ... An owner could own multiple  projects and the admin should be able to see everything and to do everything.

Loopback seem to have the possibility to define that.

How would you approach that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, define static roles in your boot scripts
eq: TeamMeamber, Owner, Admin, etc

see this example https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Defining-and-using-roles.html#static-roles

```
//create the admin role
Role.create({
  name: 'admin'
}, function(err, role) {

});
```

Then register RoleResolver in your boot scripts for your roles. This is the logic for determining wheter for  arequest, the role applies or not.

From the example at the above link.

```
Role.registerResolver('teamMember', function(role, context, cb) {
    // Q: Is the current request accessing a Project?
    if (context.modelName !== 'project') {
      // A: No. This role is only for projects: callback with FALSE
      return process.nextTick(() => cb(null, false));
    }

    //Q: Is the user logged in? (there will be an accessToken with an ID if so)
    var userId = context.accessToken.userId;
    if (!userId) {
      //A: No, user is NOT logged in: callback with FALSE
      return process.nextTick(() => cb(null, false));
    }

    // Q: Is the current logged-in user associated with this Project?
    // Step 1: lookup the requested project
    context.model.findById(context.modelId, function(err, project) {
      // A: The datastore produced an error! Pass error to callback
      if(err) return cb(err);
      // A: There's no project by this ID! Pass error to callback
      if(!project) return cb(new Error("Project not found"));

      // Step 2: check if User is part of the Team associated with this Project
      // (using count() because we only want to know if such a record exists)
      var Team = app.models.Team;
      Team.count({
        ownerId: project.ownerId,
        memberId: userId
      }, function(err, count) {
        // A: The datastore produced an error! Pass error to callback
        if (err) return cb(err);

        if(count > 0){
          // A: YES. At least one Team associated with this User AND Project
          // callback with TRUE, user is role:`teamMember`
          return cb(null, true);
        }

        else{
          // A: NO, User is not in this Project's Team
          // callback with FALSE, user is NOT role:`teamMember`
          return cb(null, false);
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

Then in you Models, use these roles by their names,

```
{
  "accessType": "READ",
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "admin",
  "permission": "ALLOW",
  "property": "findById"
}
```

So basically,

1. you create a few roles
2. then declare in your model definition what roles
   have access to access to READ, WRITE or EXECUTE custom (list of)
   methods
3. And then use a role resolver which will run for those models which have those roles and decide if the roles apply in the current context of the request.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, using that method I don't think I can say memberA can access to projectA but not projectB isn't it?

Comment: You can. Have a mapping model for that. For this particular case, set the model as attributes as ProjectID, MemberID.

In your role resolver, get the current projectID and memberID from the current context and then check if that particular mapping exists. If it does return true in the resolver, else return false.

You can even have another attribute in the mapping model for Roles as an Array (or maybe further normalise it depending on your use case) and check if the member belongs to the project and has that role.

Hope that answers your question

Comment: Thanks Karan, over the weekend i'll try to do it and I'll get back to you in case of problems ore once I fixed it :)

Comment: I can create roles following the docs but every time I restart loopback the role created loses its users. is there a way for avoiding that? Thanks

Comment: are you using a persistent datasource such as mysql or mongoDB for roles model? check you server/model-config.json. Loopback creates an Inmemory connector by the name of 'db' by default. Make sure that's not the problem. In case you wanna use the memory connector, just use 'file' attribute for persisteing memory db to storage

Comment: Hi, I solved that problem thanks. As you suggested I used registerResolver() and specific  the role. The problem is that now I have multiple roles and each time a request is received all the handler registered using registerResolver() are triggered. I don't think this is normal. Any idea? Thanks